# Add extra menu to theme

Tags: menus

What's the best way to add an extra menu location to a theme that already has one?

I want to add an extra menu in a child theme of a theme that currently has a single custom menu (what is the correct terminology here?!).

Do I just use `register_nav_menu()` to create an additional menu?

Comment: The answer is simple, and I believe you knew before asking.

Comment: @JeremyJared - pointless and incorrect accusation. The answer doesn't seem to be that simple as 2 people didn't get it right, which is why I spent some time working it out myself. You'll see my answer predates yours.

Comment: @Jeremy Jared FYI there is nothing wrong with asking a question you know answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question

Both `register_nav_menu()` and `register_nav_menus()` are **additive**, ie they add to the existing menu set (as long as you use a different location identifier). You don't need to redeclare an existing custom menu location that was created with either one of those calls.

Answer (score 1):

there are two functions to register the menus: 1. register_nav_menu 2. register_nav_menus . The first registers only one menu location the other accepts arrays of menus. Thus, if you would like to add a new menu location you will need to use register_nav_menus();

```
    register_nav_menus( array(
                    'your_current_menu_location' => __( 'Your current menu label', 'your_theme' ),
                    'additional_location_' => __( 'Your additional menu label', 'your_theme'),

        //etc...
                ) );
```

Comment: I need to add ADDITIONAL menus - your answer does not make it clear if this works for this situation.

Comment: this code adds support for 3 menus, with three locations: top primary and footer. You can add as many as you like in the array.

Comment: Does your answer overwrite any existing locations that were already defined in the theme.

Comment: How is your menu registered now? by register_nav_menu();?

Comment: Any way, let's say that what you have now is `<?php register_nav_menu( 'main', 'Main Menu' ); ?>`. To add another one you need to use `register_nav_menus();` (instead of the `register_nav_menu`) like this:

`register_nav_menus( array(
            'main' => 'Main Menu',
            'additional menu' => 'Additional Menu Label'
        ) );
`

Essentially you are declaring your old menu and the new menu in that array

Comment: As per other answers and discussion there is no reason to re-declare old menu. It won't break anything but it won't essentially do anything either (it will just overwrite it with same data internally).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this to the functions.php file for your theme, and remove the existing nav_menu function:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
  array(
    // Add Your Current Menu Register Here And Replace The Current Code With This
    'secondary' => 'secondary' ,
    'tertiary' =>  'tertiary',
    )
  );
}
?>
```

**To use the menu's you would place this in the template desired:**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
```

**OR:**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'tertiary' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: The existing menu registration does not need to be removed - both register_nav_menu(s) functions are additive - ie they add to the set of menus that's already there.

Comment: OK, then follow the above instructions minus the part that says remove the existing function. You seem to think you know enough to correct everyone, but you can't figure out how to add an additional menu?

Comment: @Jeremy Jared let's keep things friendly, ok? I don't see why trivial comment with clarification is bringing out such seemingly aggressive response here.